# ngrx state keeps getting overwritten

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am using ngrx to maintain my application state.

I have a angularjs4 application with two different modules that which has two different reducers,effects etc.

One is for authenticate and another is to get list of movies. But I see whichever effect is called second it over writes the global app state with its value.

How do I prevent this?

Here is the state definition in my auth module

```
import {User} from "../../models/user";

export interface State {
    user: User,
    isLoggedIn: boolean,
    errors: any[]
}

export const initialState: State = {
    user: null,
    isLoggedIn:false,
    errors:[]
};
```

This is the auth reducer

```
import * as fromAuth from './auth.state';
import * as AuthActions from './auth.actions';

export function authReducer(state = fromAuth.initialState, action: AuthActions.ALL){
    console.log('authReducer', action, state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case AuthActions.LOGIN_WITH_GOOGLE:
            return {...state};

        case AuthActions.LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK:
            return {...state};

        case AuthActions.LOGIN_WITH_TWITTER:
            return {...state};

        case AuthActions.LOGOUT:
            return {...state, user: null, isLoggedIn:false};

        case AuthActions.LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL:
            return {...state};

        case AuthActions.LOGIN_FAILED:
            return {...state, errors:[{}]};

        case AuthActions.REGISTER_USER:
            return {...state};

        case AuthActions.USER_REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL:
            return {...state, user: action.payload, isLoggedIn:true};

        case AuthActions.USER_REGISTRATION_FAILED:
            return {...state, errors:[{}]};

    }
}
```

auth module definition

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    EffectsModule.forFeature([AuthEffects]),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule

  ],
  exports:[AppRoutingModule],
  declarations: [
      LoginComponent
  ],
  providers: [AuthService]
})
```

Below is the movies state definition

```
import {Movie} from "../../models/movie";

export interface State{
    all:Movie[],
    selectedMovie:Movie,
    isLoading:boolean,
    errors:any[]
}

export const initialState: State = {
    all:[],
    selectedMovie:null,
    isLoading:false,
    errors:[]
};
```

Movie Reducer

```
import * as MovieActions from './movies.actions';
import * as fromMovie from './movies.state';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export function movieReducer(state = fromMovie.initialState, action:MovieActions.ALL) {
    console.log('movieReducer', action, state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case MovieActions.GET_ALL_MOVIES:
            return _.assign({}, state, {loading:true});
            // return {...state, loading:true};

        case MovieActions.GET_MOVIES_BY_TYPE:
            return _.assign({}, state, {loading:true});

        case MovieActions.GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS:
            return _.assign({}, state,{all: action.payload} ,{loading:false});
            // return {...state, all: action.payload, loading:false };

        case MovieActions.SELECT_MOVIE:
            return _.assign({}, state,{selectedMovie: action.payload} ,{loading:false});
            // return {...state, selectedMovie:action.payload};

        case MovieActions.UPDATE_MOVIE:
            return {};

        case MovieActions.DELETE_MOVIE:
            return {};
    }
}
```

finally movie module

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        VgCoreModule,
        VgControlsModule,
        VgOverlayPlayModule,
        VgBufferingModule,
        HttpModule,
        MdCardModule,
        MdButtonModule,
        RouterModule,
        EffectsModule.forFeature([MoviesEffects])
    ],
    exports: [
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        MoviesListComponent,
        WatchMovieComponent,
        EditMovieComponent,
        ListFromObjectPipe
    ],
    providers: [MovieApiService]
})
export class MoviesModule {
}
```

Root app state

```
import * as fromMoviesReducer from '../movies/store/movies.reducer';
import * as fromMoviesState from '../movies/store/movies.state';
import * as fromAuthReducer from '../auth/store/auth.reducer';
import * as fromAuthState from '../auth/store/auth.state';
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';

export interface AppState {
    movies: fromMoviesState.State;
    user:fromAuthState.State;
}

export const appReducers : ActionReducerMap<any> = {
    movies: fromMoviesReducer.movieReducer,
    user: fromAuthReducer.authReducer
};
```

finally app module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        TabsComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MdToolbarModule,
        MdTabsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MoviesModule,
        ChatModule,
        GamesModule,
        AuthModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        MdButtonModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot(appReducers),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
        StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
            maxAge: 25 //  Retains last 25 states
        })
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: code is appreciated

Comment: added some code, please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: really answer and code is appreciated. question is helpfull

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got the answer from an awesome developer in Glitter! I didn't have default state in my reducers! Adding default state as follows fixed the issue.

```
switch (action.type) {
  /* my actions */

  default:
    return state;

}
```